# Batch file in windows 7 to find files not matching pattern

Tags: regex, batch-file, command-line

Was hoping you could help me. I need to write a small batch file that can sit on a users pc (not an extremely computer literate person) to check a folder (that is shared from the server) and list the files in this folder that does not match a file pattern. I have an application that runs every night, but the files have to be named `*_*_*.*` The application fails if it isn't in this format and even though the app will give some indication of which file was incorrect, they waste a day and if they get it wrong again...another day. They need to be able to run this simple batch file and it can just on screen display the incorrectly named files.

I started reading about the forFiles function, but haven't been able to figure out how to use it properly. Also, will I be able to directly reference this shared folder? Now if we access it, it looks something like this: \dhpServer1\PeopleFolder. In here are the files that should be checked.

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a full list of files and filter those not matching the required pattern.

```dos
dir /b /a-d "\\dhpServer1\PeopleFolder\*" | findstr /v /r /c:"^[^_][^_]*_[^_][^_]*_.*"
```

The `findstr` will filter the output of the `dir` command, showing the lines that does not match (`/v`) the regular expresion (`/r`) indicated (`/c:`) :

```
^     at the start of the line
[^_]  a non underscore character
[^_]* followed by zero or more non underscore characters
_     followed by an underscore
[^_]  followed by a non underscore character
[^_]* followed by zero or more non underscore characters
_     followed by an underscore
.*    followed by any sequence of zero or more characters
```

Probably the expression needs to be adjusted. This expression is just *my interpretation* (and of course I can be wrong) of what you have written as  `*_*_*.*`, but does not match the behaviour of the wildcard in the `dir` command. `"^[^_]*_[^_]*_.*"` is closer to the behaviour of the indicated wildcard expression.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "errorfound="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
  ) DO (
 SET "error="
 FOR /f "tokens=1-3*delims=_" %%p IN ("q%%a") DO (
  IF "%%p" equ "q" SET error=Y
  IF "%%s" neq ""  SET error=Y
  IF "%%r" equ ""  SET error=Y
  IF NOT DEFINED error (
   FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=." %%x IN ("q%%r") DO (
    IF "%%x" equ "q" SET error=Y
    IF "%%y" equ ""  SET error=Y
    IF "%%z" neq ""  SET error=Y
   )
  )
  IF DEFINED error (
   ECHO %%a is invalid FORMAT
   SET errorfound=y
  ) ELSE (ECHO %%a is OK)
 )
)
IF DEFINED errorfound (
 ECHO error found
 PAUSE
) ELSE (
 ECHO All OK!
 timeout /t 5 >nul
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Here's a sample output:

```
a_valid_file.name is OK
_invalid_file.namestartingunderscore is invalid FORMAT
an_invalid_file_name.toomanyundescores is invalid FORMAT
invalid_file.nameinsufficientunderscores is invalid FORMAT
an_invalid_.filenameterminalunderscoreinname is invalid FORMAT
an_extra_invalid_.filenameterminalunderscoreinname is invalid FORMAT
an_invalid_filenamewithnoextension is invalid FORMAT
an_invalid_filenamewith.multiple.extensions is invalid FORMAT
error found
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If all of the files are in valid format, the procedure should show an apprpriate message for 5 seconds and terminate.

The principle is to evaluate the separate parts of the name by tokenising when `_` and `.` are used as separators and exploiting the `if defined` characteristic to switch whether an error has occured on an instance-by-instance basis.